# Query SQlite Database where month is equal to...?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Spent about a week on this.

I have got an Android App which I want a listview of items based on their month.

So in the database I have DateTime column which looks like this in the DB
  - 2015-10-24 07:53:04

I am using ADB atm so I can check I am using the correct sql. This is the query I am using

```
select * from itemtable where date = strftime('%m', '10');
```

So I am looking to get the rows where the date is the 10th month.
I get nothing back off the query. When using strftime it works fine.

I must be missing something. Any help would be fantastic!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use substring function to cut the month part out of data as

```
 select * from itemtable where substr(date,3,2)=10;
```

Substring function is used as

```
Substr(col_name, start-pos, length);
```